# Problema com matriz de adjacência

Tags: c, matriz, estrutura-de-dados, malloc

Eu estou com dificuldades para imprimir os dados de uma matriz, acredito que esteja salvando os dados da maneira errada, pelo que percebe os dados não foram salvos pois quando vou imprimir não volta nenhum dado que adicionei, eu tentei evitar de adicionar dados pela leitura de arquivos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct matriz
{
    int n_elementos;
    int **elementos;
} Matriz;

Matriz * cria_matriz(Matriz *m, int mat[5][5])
{
    m->elementos = malloc(m->n_elementos * sizeof(int *));

    for (int i = 0; i < m->n_elementos; i++)
    {
        m->elementos[i] = calloc(m->n_elementos , sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < m->n_elementos; j++)
        {
            m->elementos[i][j] = mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return m;
}

void imprimir_matriz(Matriz m)
{
   printf("Matriz\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < m.n_elementos; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.n_elementos; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", m.elementos[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    Matriz m;
    int mat[5][5] = {0, 185, 119, 152, 133, 185, 0, 121, 150, 200, 199,121, 0, 174, 120, 152, 150, 174, 0, 199, 133, 200, 120, 199, 0};

    cria_matriz(&m, mat);
    imprimir_matriz(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vejamos...

Vou listar os erros observados um a um, separados por cada função. Tente verificar se consegue percebê-los para que aprenda para seu futuro, OK?

---

`cria_matriz(...)`

**1** - Não tem por que você usar o tipo `Matriz *` para a função `cria_matriz(...)`. *Por quê?* Simplesmente por que você passou o endereço de `m` como argumento a função. Toda modificação será feita no próprio `m` passado como argumento. Assim sendo, sua função fica definida assim:

```
    void cria_matriz( Matriz *m, int mat[5][5] ){ ... }
```

**2** - É sempre uma boa prática fazer um *[type casting](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/footnotes/cast.html)* do tipo do ponteiro recebendo alocação de memória. Suas alocações ficariam:

```
    m->elementos    = (int **) malloc( m->n_elementos * sizeof(int *) )
    ...
    m->elementos[i] = (int *)  calloc( m->n_elementos, sizeof(int) );
```

**3** - `m->n_elementos` não foi definido ao ser criado. Isso por que `m` é um ponteiro. Logo, podemos assumir que seu tamanho é `0`. Isso vai fazer com que você crie nenhuma memória para `m->elementos` ou `m->elementos[n]`. Assim, antes de alocar memória com `malloc(...)` ou `calloc(...)`, você precisa definir o tamanho de `m->n_elementos`:

```
    m->n_elementos = 5 * 5; /* 5 linhas * 5 colunas */
```

**4** - Em verdade, você não quer definir o espaço de cada linha e coluna da matriz `m` com `m->n_elementos` já que este é o total de elementos. Sua `matriz[5][5]` tem um total de `25` elementos porém divididos em 5 linhas e 5 colunas.

Pensando nisso, em `malloc(...)` você deve substituir por 5 linhas e em `calloc(...)` deve substituí-lo por 5 colunas. Efetivamente, você cria o espaço para 5 linhas com `malloc(...)` e cada linha recebe 5 elementos de `calloc(...)`. Portanto:

```
    m->elementos    = (int **) malloc( 5 * sizeof(int *) ); /* 5 linhas */
    ...
    m->elementos[i] = (int *)  calloc( 5, sizeof(int) ); /* 5 colunas */
```

Cada um dos laços `for` utilizados também precisam ser alterados:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {...} /* 5 linhas */
    ...
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {...} /* 5 colunas */
```

**5** - Tanto `LINHAS` como `COLUNAS` foram criados com a [diretiva](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/apend/preprocessor.html) de pré-processamento `#define`. Foram usados para tornar o código mais legível. São colocadas logo após os `#include`:

```
    #include ...

    #define LINHAS  5
    #define COLUNAS 5
```

Foram substitutos de `m->n_elementos em` em `malloc(...)`, `calloc(...)` e laços `for`, mencionados no **item 4**, como segue:

```
    m->elementos    = (int **) malloc( LINHAS * sizeof(int *) );
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < LINHAS; i++) {...}
    ...
    m->elementos[i] = (int *)  calloc( COLUNAS, sizeof(int) );
    ...
    for (int j = 0; j < COLUNAS; j++) {...}
```

O mesmo foi feito para `m->n_elementos` mencionado no **item 3**:

```
    m->n_elementos = LINHAS * COLUNAS;
```

---

**Nos casos seguintes, serei mais econômico com exemplos de código. Não há motivo para chover no molhado pois os exemplos são os mesmos. No final também será mostrado o código completo e funcional.**

---

`imprimir_matriz(...);`

**1** - Aqui a recomendação é mudar o parâmetro de imprimir_matriz(...) para ponteiro, evitando criar memória extra. Se for considerar que toda a temática é alocação dinâmica, mais correto ainda. Veja:

```
    void imprimir_matriz(Matriz *m){...}
```

**2** - Como agora `m` internamente a `imprimir_matriz(...)` é ponteiro, deve-se trocar `.` por `->`.

**3** - Seguindo a mesma lógica apontada no **item 4** e melhorado no **item 5** de `cria_matriz(...)`, teríamos mudanças nos laços `for` conforme apontado.

---

`main()`

**1** - Recomendo trocar a definição de `matriz[5][5]` para `matriz[LINHAS][COLUNAS]`.

**2** - Recomendo atribuir os valores da matriz separados por cada linha e coluna. Isso pois `-Wall` é muito usado ao compilar um código C pois fornece avisos de estruturas não muito aceitas por certos desenvolvedores. Tem-se:

```
    int mat[LINHAS][COLUNAS] = { 
        {   0, 185, 119, 152, 133 }, 
        { 185,   0, 121, 150, 200 }, 
        { 199, 121,   0, 174, 120 }, 
        { 152, 150, 174,   0, 199 }, 
        { 133, 200, 120, 199,   0 } 
    };
```

**3** - Precisa-se alterar a chamada de `imprimir_matriz(...)` para fornecer o endereço do de `m`:

```
    imprimir_matriz( &m );
```

**4** - Umas das primeiras coisas que devemos criar é a função que vai liberar a memórias do que foi alocado pois já temos planejada a estrutura de dados a ser criada. Presumo que esteja na lista de afazeres.

---

### Código funcional

Segue seu código de maneira funcional, com os problemas corrigidos. Era uma cadeia de erros possíveis de serem corrigidos por você mas que fatores outros podem ter atrapalhado a percepção dos erros presentes. Sem mais delongas:

**Diretivas de pré processamento:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define LINHAS 5
#define COLUNAS 5
```

**Estrutura de dados:**

```
typedef struct matriz
{
    int n_elementos;
    int **elementos;

} Matriz;
```

**Função** `cria_matriz(...)`**:**

```
void cria_matriz( Matriz *m, int mat[5][5] ){

    int i, j;

    m->n_elementos = LINHAS * COLUNAS;

    m->elementos = (int **) malloc( LINHAS * sizeof(int *) );

    for ( i = 0; i < LINHAS; i++ ){

        m->elementos[i] = (int *) calloc( COLUNAS , sizeof(int) );

        for ( j = 0; j < COLUNAS; j++ ) m->elementos[i][j] = mat[i][j];

    }

}
```

**Função** `imprimir_matriz(...)`**:**

```
void imprimir_matriz( Matriz *m ){

    int i, j;

    printf("\nMatriz\n\n");

    for( i = 0; i < LINHAS; i++ ){

        for( j = 0; j < COLUNAS; j++ ) printf("%d ", m->elementos[i][j]);

        printf("\n");

    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

**Função** `main()`**:**

```
int main(){

    Matriz m;
    int mat[LINHAS][COLUNAS] = { 
        {   0, 185, 119, 152, 133 }, 
        { 185,   0, 121, 150, 200 }, 
        { 199, 121,   0, 174, 120 }, 
        { 152, 150, 174,   0, 199 }, 
        { 133, 200, 120, 199,   0 } 
    };

    cria_matriz( &m, mat );

    imprimir_matriz( &m );

    /* Crie uma função limpar_matriz( &m ) */

    return 0;

}
```

**Saída:**

```
Matriz

0 185 119 152 133 
185 0 121 150 200 
199 121 0 174 120 
152 150 174 0 199 
133 200 120 199 0
```

Este código pode ser encontrado em uma versão um *tiquinho* melhor e compilável com `-pedantic -ansi -Wall -Wextra -Werror` [aqui](https://github.com/jfcandidofilho/stackoverflow/tree/master/371255). Recomendo olhar só depois de fazer sua própria função de limpeza de memória. Também recomendo procurar sobre o [Valgrind](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) (tutorial [aqui](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~rafael/cursos/2s2018/mc202/valgrind.html)) para auxiliar em *vazamento de memória*.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda meu amigo.

Comment: Sem problemas. E se a resposta resolveu seu problema, marque a resposta como correta para poder ajudar mais pessoas com problemas similares. Caso contrário, nenhuma ação a mais será necessária. Happy coding!